# Inconsistence when converting time string to timestamp using python in Mac OS

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp, timezone

I tried to convert some time strings to timestamp using Python (pkg time & datetime). Unexpected things happened when I converted time strings during 2AM period. It will reconsider timezone in the timestamp value for no reason.

Here are four timestrings around 2 AM, I convert each of them to timestamp using datetime and time, respectively.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
timestrings = ["2008-10-26 02:55:26", "2008-10-26 02:55:31", "2008-10-26 02:59:59", "2008-10-26 03:00:02"]
for i in range(1, len(timestrings)):
    ts00 = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(timestrings[i-1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    ts10 = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(timestrings[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(ts00-ts10)
    ts01 = time.mktime(time.strptime(timestrings[i-1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    ts11 = time.mktime(time.strptime(timestrings[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(ts01-ts11)
```

Considering the local timezone (mine is UTC+1), the values maybe different, but the differences between pairwise values should be consistent, which means the outputs should be

```
5.0
5.0
268.0
268.0
3.0
3.0
```

However, my outputs was

```
5.0
3605.0
268.0
268.0
3603.0
3.0
```

This inconsistence happened both in time and datetime, but in different time points when I ran it in IOS system. When I tested it in windows & linux system and everything is ok. I also tested a lot of records in string format, this inconsistence occured randomly and rarely. I can only find out a question mentioning "ambiguous 2AM cases"[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464009/calculate-tm-isdst-from-date-and-timezone]. Is it some weird curse for IOS system?